# SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 has no Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, ssms, sql-server-2005-express

Where is the configuration manager for SQL Express 2005?  I need to configure SQL Server for TCP/IP but there is no configuration manager with the package.  I see SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard, I see SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access, but no Configuration Manager.  According to the MSDN, there should be one.  I've even looked online for a download of the Configuration Manager for SQL Server 2005, but could not find one.   Did I miss something in the download or should I just scrap SQL Server Express and download the full-blown SQL Server for Developers?

Answer (score 2):

[This might be](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) what you are looking for.  I have used it with SQL Server Express 2005 <strike>although I am not sure if it configures the specific things you want to change</strike> and I just now verified that it does provide access to the communications options.

Comment: That should be it. The GUI tools were not included.

Comment: SQL 2008 Version:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2):

My SQL Server 2005 Express Configuration Manager shortcut launches:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\mmc.exe /32 "C:\WINDOWS\system32\SQLServerManager.msc"
```

If you don't have the start menu shortcuts, try running that from the run menu/command prompt. Check in the `C:\WINDOWS\system32\` folder to make sure the `SQLServerManager.msc` file exists.

Comment: and for 64 OS
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mmc.exe" /32 "c:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager.msc"

Answer (score 1):

It should be installed as part of your SQL Express 2005 installation. Perhaps you arent looking at the right place. In a typical installation, you will find the configuration manager in here (word may not match as I just typed in as I can remember)

```
Start -> Program -> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -> Configuration Tool -> Configuration Manager
```

Comment: For the full version, but for Express; I don't think it was included.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this "SQL Server 2005 service pack 3"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb895958

It installs lots of utilities including the configuration manager.

I encountered this same issue with a particular machine (cuz usually -with other machines- it gets installed with normal SQL EXPRESS 2005 installer)